# SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243)

Tags: python, apache-spark

I see several post that contain the same error as the error that I am receiving, but none are leading me to a fix on my code. I have used this exact same code many times with no issue and now am having problems. Here is the error I receive:

```
y4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243).
```

Here is how I start my context within my python script:

```
spark = ps.sql.SparkSession.builder \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .appName("collab_rec") \
        .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/bgg.game_commen$
        .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sc.setCheckpointDir('checkpoint/')
sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)
```

Please let me know if you have a suggestion.

Comment: Why do you need the SQLContext ? SparkSession should be enough

Comment: @eliasah that is a good point. Unfortunately, after I found a way to get my spark session running without an error, I am receiving an error when loading a dataframe from mongo, which has worked before, but might end up being a separate post if I can't figure that out today!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SparkSession is the new entry point in Spark 2.x. This is a replacement for SQLContext, however it uses SQLContext in internal code.

Everything you were making with SQLContext should be possible with SparkSession.

If you really want to use SQLContext, use spark.sqlContext variable

Comment: As I noted above my issue is another one entirely, however, this answer does give useful information about Spark 2.x that I recently figured out myself. Honestly, I have produced this error before while only initiating a SparkSession as well, but hopefully, the answer here gives useful information to users.

Comment: what will be possible configuration of sparksession to avoid this error.

Comment: @Kalyan Not use SQLContext but SparkSession or use sqlContext = spark.sqlContext. Configuration will be the same

Comment: @T.Gawęda i used sparksession only in my flask-spark application for testing purpose but i am facing this error. My current posted question will might help you to realize my situation . Here it is
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45707205/how-to-solve-py4jjavaerrorcalling-none-org-apache-spark-api-java-javasparkconte