# How to solve Py4JJavaError:calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext

Tags: apache-spark, flask, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to build a flask-spark application using pyspark. For testing purpose I will give a sqlstring in url which will be process in Spark script and will return json data to the browser as response.Here is my code.

```
import re
from tkinter import*
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from flask import Flask
#from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
#conf=SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName("TestValue")
#sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
#sqlContext=HiveContext(sc)
#from pyspark.sql import Row
import json



app=Flask(__name__)
spark=SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "C:\spark\spark-warehouse").appName("TestApp").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
print("Success")

#sqlstring="SELECT lflow1.LeaseType as LeaseType, lflow1.Status as Status, lflow1.Property as property, lflow1.City as City, lesflow2.DealType as DealType, lesflow2.Area as Area, lflow1.Did as DID, lesflow2.MID as MID from lflow1, lesflow2  WHERE lflow1.Did = lesflow2.MID"
@app.route('/<sqlval>')
def queryBuilder(sqlval):
    df=spark.sql(sqlval)
    #df.show()

    resultlist = df.toJSON().collect()
    dumpdata = re.sub(r"\'", "", str(resultlist))
    jsondata = json.dumps(dumpdata)
    #print(jsondata)
    return jsondata

    #return df

#queryBuilder(sqlstring)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)

master=Tk()
entryval=Entry(master)
entryval.grid(row=0,column=1)
Button(master,text='Quit',command=master.quit).grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W,pady=50)
mainloop()
```

here the sqlstring will come from browser url in localhost and access into querybuilder function which will return json data to browser as response . when i am running spark submit this error has [image]occured

**py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). To ignore this error, set spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true. The currently running SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)**

May be i am missing some configuration property here. but could not figure it out.I have read related post about this they have mentioned sparksession is enough, i dont need sqlcontext but could you help me out how to solve this issue with sparksession,that means ***How could i configure SparkSession to avoid this issue*** .Kindly help me to figure it out. Thanks

Here is my SqlCOntext Style code

```
import re
from tkinter import*
import json
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
#from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from flask import Flask
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
conf=SparkConf("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts = true").setMaster('local').setAppName("TestValue")
sc=SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext=HiveContext(sc)
#from pyspark.sql import Row




app=Flask(__name__)
#spark=SparkSession.builder.config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "C:\spark\spark-warehouse").appName("TestApp").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
print("Success")

#sqlstring="SELECT lflow1.LeaseType as LeaseType, lflow1.Status as Status, lflow1.Property as property, lflow1.City as City, lesflow2.DealType as DealType, lesflow2.Area as Area, lflow1.Did as DID, lesflow2.MID as MID from lflow1, lesflow2  WHERE lflow1.Did = lesflow2.MID"
@app.route('/<sqlval>')
def queryBuilder(sqlval):
    df=sqlContext.sql(sqlval)
    #df.show()

    resultlist = df.toJSON().collect()
    dumpdata = re.sub(r"\'", "", str(resultlist))
    jsondata = json.dumps(dumpdata)
    #print(jsondata)
    return jsondata

    #return df

#queryBuilder(sqlstring)
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug = True)

master=Tk()
entryval=Entry(master)
entryval.grid(row=0,column=1)
Button(master,text='Quit',command=master.quit).grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W,pady=50)
mainloop()
```

And i am getting same error

Comment: You don't need to create a spark context when you are using a spark session. `spark` is your SparkSession, use `spark.sparkContext` to use SparkContext

Comment: well i have read that. but could you suggest me how could i  configure sparksession  for avoiding this problem

Comment: Ok, sorry - my misunderstanding. This is not a exact duplicate, other community members - please also vote on reopening

Comment: please help me out to re opening. i need it badly .Thanks for your help

Comment: I'm not ok with opening this. I'm sorry. I've already discussed this once with you before. Setting multiple context isn't recommended.

Comment: @T.Gawęda philantrovert is right.

Comment: @eliasah  i have tried here only sparksessoin  not sqlcontext . if you see my code then you will see i didnt use sqlcontext here . there are some commented line those are unnecessary

Comment: If in case this is not a dupe, we'll need a MVCE to be able to reproduce the error.

Comment: I have given the code with SQLContext style but getting same error. could you help me out , why this is now happening, sorry for disturbing , i am new in spark .Thanks

Comment: I think this problem is due to Flask development mode. The python code will reload in this mode.